# How to create multiple HTML pages with same layout?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website that has a similar format with all of the pages is there a way to have a template so you don't have to retype the same code over and over again so that if I want to redesign the website I only have to redesign the main template instead of every page

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: I'm not aware of any frameworks I'm new to web dev, please advise of one if it can help

Comment: Even though I would not advise doing it with plain JS, you have [templates literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). If you want to go with a framework such as Vue.JS, React etc you'll have a way to easily create templates. You can also go with PHP that will allow you to include bits of code into another file.

Comment: You can use javascript to create the html. Use a common function which will create the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating multiple HTML pages with the same layout is exactly the reason why frameworks such vuejs and react are so popular. if you are new in web dev I can recommend you vuejs. It's very easy to learn.